# Python convert complex String to List of Dict

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to convert this object unicode or str to list/array of dict, the input data is:

```
[('ALMAFUERTE', 328), ('ALAMAFUERTE', 1), ('ALMFUERTE', 1), ('ALMZFUERTE', 1)]
```

Is a column of csv, I import this with PANDAS, but I need something similar to array of dict for processing

```
[{'ALMAFUERTE': 328}, {'ALAMAFUERTE': 1}, {'ALMFUERTE': 1}, {'ALMZFUERTE': 1}]
```

Thanks.

Comment: `[dict(l)]`, if `l` is your input list

Comment: `[{i:j} for i, j in l]`

Comment: @sacul please view my coment of Brandon Wang answer

Comment: If that's what your CSV file looks like, then it's not a CSV file.

Comment: More to the point: how did you get that file? Did you write some code that just does something like `f.write(str(list_of_pairs))`? If so, _that_ is the code you need to fix. You should be writing data in some format that's meant to be read back and parsed, like JSON or CSV, not just storing the Python string representation and then hoping you can figure out how to parse it later.

Comment: But exactly have you done? Please share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `"[('ALMAFUERTE', 328), ('ALAMAFUERTE', 1), ('ALMFUERTE', 1), ('ALMZFUERTE', 1)]"` is your input, you need to turn it into a list using the `eval()` method.

```
>>> l = "[('ALMAFUERTE', 328), ('ALAMAFUERTE', 1), ('ALMFUERTE', 1), ('ALMZFUERTE', 1)]"
>>> eval(l)
[('ALMAFUERTE', 328), ('ALAMAFUERTE', 1), ('ALMFUERTE', 1), ('ALMZFUERTE', 1)]
```

Then you can do this:

```
>>> l = [('ALMAFUERTE', 328), ('ALAMAFUERTE', 1), ('ALMFUERTE', 1), ('ALMZFUERTE', 1)]
>>> [{i :j} for i, j in l]
[{'ALMAFUERTE': 328}, {'ALAMAFUERTE': 1}, {'ALMFUERTE': 1}, {'ALMZFUERTE': 1}]
```

If you are using a pandas DataFrame that is structured like this:

```
>>> l = [('ALMAFUERTE', 328), ('ALAMAFUERTE', 1), ('ALMFUERTE', 1), ('ALMZFUERTE', 1)]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['name', 'val'])
          name  val
0   ALMAFUERTE  328
1  ALAMAFUERTE    1
2    ALMFUERTE    1
3   ALMZFUERTE    1
```

You can do this:

```
>>> d = []
>>> for _, row in df.iterrows():
        d.append({row['name']:row['val']})

>>> print(d)
[{'ALMAFUERTE': 328}, {'ALAMAFUERTE': 1}, {'ALMFUERTE': 1}, {'ALMZFUERTE': 1}]
```

Comment: It's perfect if the data type is a list, but I need to convert my data type to list, and when I list (l) it returns this: ['[', '(', "'", 'A', 'L', 'M', 'A', 'F', 'U', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'E', "'", ',', ' ', '3', '2', '8', ')', ',', ' ', '(', "'", 'A', 'L', 'A', 'M', 'A', 'F', 'U', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'E', "'", ',', ' ', '1', ')', ',', ' ', '(', "'", 'A', 'L', 'M', 'F', 'U', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'E', "'", ',', ' ', '1', ')', ',', ' ', '(', "'", 'A', 'L', 'M', 'Z', 'F', 'U', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'E', "'", ',', ' ', '1', ')', ']'] the type inport is <type 'unicode'>

Comment: If the input is a string, you can use the `eval()` method. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks Brandom, with eval() works perfectly. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @user3483203 what is a reason?

Comment: @GermanAvalos they might be referring to this [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)